# Why mongod.service is killed by my system?

Tags: mongodb

I am using **MongoDB 4.4** version on **ubuntu 20.4**, using *2 mongo instances* on the same server. I encountered this problem:

```
Sep 03 10:45:25 mlnode systemd[1]: Stopping MongoDB Database Server...
Sep 03 10:45:25 mlnode systemd[1]: mongod.service: Succeeded.
Sep 03 10:45:25 mlnode systemd[1]: Stopped MongoDB Database Server.
Sep 03 10:45:25 mlnode systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Sep 03 10:55:46 mlnode systemd[1]: Stopping MongoDB Database Server...
Sep 03 10:55:46 mlnode systemd[1]: mongod.service: Succeeded.
Sep 03 10:55:46 mlnode systemd[1]: Stopped MongoDB Database Server.
Sep 03 10:55:46 mlnode systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Sep 03 11:05:05 mlnode systemd[1]: Stopping MongoDB Database Server...
Sep 03 11:05:05 mlnode systemd[1]: mongod.service: Succeeded.
Sep 03 11:05:05 mlnode systemd[1]: Stopped MongoDB Database Server.
Sep 03 11:05:05 mlnode systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Sep 03 11:13:20 mlnode systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service:11: PIDFile= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid → /run/mongodb/mongod.pid; please update the unit file accordingly.
Sep 03 11:25:47 mlnode systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service:11: PIDFile= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid → /run/mongodb/mongod.pid; please update the unit file accordingly.
Sep 03 11:56:47 mlnode systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Sep 03 11:56:47 mlnode systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'signal'
```

Wondering why the system is killing `mongod.service`, I don't have any clue. Then I checked my mongo logs:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-03T11:56:46.379+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23083,   "ctx":"conn10155","msg":"Invariant failure","attr":{"expr":"ret","error":"UnknownError: -31803: WT_NOTFOUND: item not found","file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_record_store.cpp","line":1598}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-03T11:56:46.379+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23084,   "ctx":"conn10155","msg":"\n\n***aborting after invariant() failure\n\n"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-03T11:56:46.379+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4757800, "ctx":"conn10155","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"Got signal: 6 (Aborted).\n"}}
```

Comment: Have you check RAM ?

Comment: yes! my server has 30 gigs of ram and when mongo failed, at that time 14 gigs of ram was available

Comment: Your data directory is corrupt.

Comment: you mean `/var/lib/mongodb` this ?

Comment: I get this too from time to time. Have you figured it out yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that my Linux `ulimits` were not set to the [recommended](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/index.html#linux-distributions-using-upstart) values of mongod instance.
One of the limits ( locked-in-memory ) was 65536 and in `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` **LimitMEMLOCK** was `infinity`.
So I've changed that to 65536, restarted the service and it was working again.

This worked for me!

Comment: I had same issue.
I followed your answer, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I had a similar issue. This resolved it.

Answer (score 2):

First, stop mongodb if you restarted:

```
sudo systemctl stop mongod
```

Next, I detected the database corruption:

```
sudo mongod --repair --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
```

Next, run commands:

```
chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Finally

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

From: https://sondnpt00343.medium.com/how-to-fix-mongod-service-32dbbe51a4ee

Answer (score 0):

First, I detected the database corruption.

```
 sudo mongod --repair --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
```

Then, I restarted the service but I faced another problem (exit-code).

Next, I ran following commands on the terminal :

```
chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb

chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Finally, I restarted the mongodb service.

```
sudo systemctl restart mongod
```

And then this worked for me very well.